# NoMethodError undefined method `where'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a NoMethodError  `` undefined method `where' for <Subscription:0x000001083aee00> ``. It's pointing to the my User model on the line `subscription.where(cancelled: nil).exists?`.

In the views I am trying to setup an if statement so I can show select content to users whose cancellation status in the Subscriptions table is not nil.

User model:

```
  has_one :subscription

    def paid?
      subscription.where(cancelled: nil).exists?
    end
```

The `has_one` relationship was there from the beginning for other parts of the app. When I add a `belongs_to` relationship I get the error `` undefined method `where' for nil:NilClass ``

Comment: what version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if subscription is an attribute of User and if cancelled is a boolean attribute of Subscription you could do...

```
def paid?
  !subscription.cancelled? if subscription
end
```

`where` can only be used if there's a one-to-many relationship between user and subscriptions, or it can be used on the Subscription class itself.

`subscription.cancelled?` will return true if it's cancelled false if it's not so prefixed with the "not" symbol as in `!subscription.cancelled?` will return true if it's not cancelled.

The reason for the trailing `... if subscription` handles the case of no subscription present for the user, in which case false (nil) will be returned.